# How to setup a ViewModel binding for a TextBox with ReactiveUI?

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, reactiveui

For some reason I can't get my textbox/property binding to work "automatically" with Reactive UI.

My DataContext is setup like this:

My ViewModel is setup in the code behind for the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; protected set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

In my WPF MainWindow.xaml I have the DataContext and the have a textbox element like this:

(Other properties ommitted)

```
<Window x:Name="Window">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, ElementName=Window}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox Name="Password" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            ...
```

In the MainWindowViewModel I have a property and field like this:

```
string _PasswordConfirmation;

public string PasswordConfirmation
{
    get { return _PasswordConfirmation; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.PasswordConfirmation, value); }
}
```

I also have a command that is setup like this:

```
var canHitOk = this.WhenAny(
    x => x.Password,
    x => x.PasswordConfirmation,
    (pass, confirm) => (pass.Value == confirm.Value && pass.Value.Length > 3));

OkCommand = new ReactiveCommand(canHitOk);
```

As you can guess, I also have the password confirmation textbox/property setup too, and the command set for a button (The password confirmation TextBox has the same problem).  Since the field/property combos are never updated in the ViewModel, the button is never enabled.

I debugged and confirmed that the ViewModel is bound to the XAML, but the text never gets updated in the field/property combos when typing in the TextBoxes.

I looked at the [sample WP7 application in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI.Sample.WP7/MainPage.xaml.cs) and they manually bind the `KeyUp` event to set the text in the text in the property/field.  If I follow this convention, I have this in my MainWindow.xaml:

```
Password.KeyUp += (o, e) =>
{
    ViewModel.Password = Password.Text;
};
```

But is that the right way to do it?  I thought Reactive UI would handle the binding as I've seen in other MVVM frameworks, unless I'm mistaken.  Is there an easier way?

**UPDATE**

As Paul Betts pointed out in the comments in his answer, you can enable the binding to automatically update by adding this property to the binding:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

which would make the TextBox element look like this:

```
<TextBox Name="Password" Text="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: How do you set the `DataContext` for your view? Are there any binding errors in the VS output window during runtime?

Comment: I added the code/xaml for the ViewModel/DataContext configuration above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that WP7 TextBox doesn't Update its binding automatically on KeyUp - this is a problem with every MVVM framework sadly.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the answer, but I'm using WPF, I just happened to look at the WP7 example because it was a little simpler.  Is WPF supposed to update the binding automatically?

Comment: WPF will do it if you set UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged