# Loaclization with ReactiveUI (RxUI)

Tags: c#, mvvm, localization, reactiveui

I looked at ReactiveUI documentation, and found nothing about localization.
Though localization question may look a little bit irrelevant to mvvm framework... But the thing is - ReactiveUI support bindings from .cs code only.

And I don't see anything better, than to set localized value for **EACH** textField/label manually from code base... Or at least bind all labels that need to be localized.

With MVVMcross we at least have bindings in xaml/axml.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use xaml bindings with ReactiveUI (example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547243/how-to-setup-a-viewmodel-binding-for-a-textbox-with-reactiveui)

Comment: @pmbanka - Does Xamarin's Android axml have bindings?